# Python list size changes once it gets out of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```
MFCC_coeffs = 12
train_data = []
current_block = []
MAX_ROWS = 29
row_counter = 0

for line in f:
    element = line.split(' ')
    if(len(element) == MFCC_coeffs+1):
        row_counter = row_counter + 1
        element = element[:-1]
        element = [float(i) for i in element]
        current_block.append(element)
        # print("HERE")
        # print(f"element = {element}, length = {len(element)}")

    elif(len(element) == 1):
        if row_counter<MAX_ROWS:
            padding = MAX_ROWS-row_counter
            while(padding):
                pad_row = [0]*MFCC_coeffs
                current_block.append(pad_row)
                padding = padding-1
            
        row_counter = 0    
        # print(f"element = {element}, length = {len(element)}")
        # print(f"current_block = {current_block}, shape = {np.shape(current_block)}")
        train_data.append(current_block)
        # print(f"train_data shape = {np.shape(train_data)}") ## PRINTS CORRECT SIZE AT THE END OF THE FILE. E.G. (370,29,12)
        current_block.clear()
        continue
    else:
        assert("Wrong Data")
    
print(f"train_data = {train_data}, shape = {np.shape(train_data)}")    ## SIZE TO (370,0)
```

In the previous block of code, I am reading a text file and storing to a `train_data` variable. As I keep going through a text file line by line, the `train_data` is appended and reaches size `(370*29*12)` by the end which is correct. However once I get out of the file read block of code, the final size of `train_data` gets reset to `(370*0)`. I have commented in block letters the part where the output is correct and where it is wrong.

Comment: You're adding the same `current_block` to the `train_data`. Try to add a copy of `current_block`, e.g. `train_data.append(current_block[:])`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks. Can u provide some resources to read what was happening before? before the correction, the next line was printing the correct size and showed that the `train_data` list was getting appended. Only when it got out of the block, its size was reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that you're appending the same reference to `current_block` to `train_data`. Consider this example:

```py
current_block = []
train_data = []

current_block = [1]
train_data.append(current_block)  # train_data = [[1]]
current_block.clear()  # train_data = [[]]

current_block.append(2) # train_data = [[2]]
train_data.append(current_block)  # train_data = [[2], [2]]
current_block.clear()  # train_data = [[], []]
```

As you see, `current_block.clear()` will the list - and subsequently all references in `train_data`.

The solution is to append a copy to `train_data`:

```py
train_data.append(current_block[:])
```

That way, the next `current_block.clear()` won't clear any data already inside `train_data`.